# manipulate/change the window.screen property values

Tags: javascript

Greetings dear community,

my goal is to spoof the screen object properties, but I **can not** just overwrite the properties by using:
`window.screen[property] = number;` or `Object.defineProperty(...)`
because these properties are **read-only**.

Therefore I wanted to kind of clone or recreate the screen object, manipulate the properties and then overwrite the whole window.screen object.

**My attempt:**

```js
var clone = Object.create(Screen.prototype);
Object.assign(clone, window.screen);
console.log(clone);
```

The prototype is cloning well but **not the properties**.
After trying to get them with the `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` and `Object.keys` functions, which did not work either ([example here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKpyrJ?editors=1010#0)), they have to be in the prototype.
So I tried this:

```js
var clone = Object.create(Screen.prototype);
Object.assign(clone,Object.getPrototypeOf(window.screen));
console.log(clone);
```

which outputs the error *"TypeError: 'get availWidth' called on an object that does not implement interface Screen."*

Iterating with a for-in loop and assigning them does output the same error.

So it seems like I have to implement the interface Screen, even though I'm not sure if my plan is working after that. Perhaps there exists a simpler solution.

**Other ideas:**

I could assign the complete screen object as prototype (like that `Object.create(screen)`) and then set own properties on the object, but then the original values are still readable.

Maybe I also somehow can create an object by using `Screen(...)` interface?

Thanks for your help and ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is easily possible by the help of the **Object.defineProperty()** method, as long as the property is configurable.

```js
var exampleProperty = 'colorDepth',
    exampleValue = 55;
    
console.log("before:", screen[exampleProperty])    

Object.defineProperty(screen, exampleProperty, {
  // add descriptor properties here if desired
  value: exampleValue
});


console.log("after:", screen[exampleProperty])
```